# SOLIDITY: Create multiple contracts from one parent contract and listen for events from child contract

Tags: ethereum, solidity

What is the best architecture to allow users to deploy their own smart contracts (NFT collections), and still be able to index the tokens created on those dynamically created contracts using something like The Graph subgraphs?

Currently the idea was to have a "Factory" contract deployed by me, so easily indexable, and inside that have a function **createCollection** that will deploy a contract using the `new <ContractName>` keyword.

Is this bad architecture? Would this even work?

The end goal is to allow users to deploy contracts from a UI, but still be able to listen for their events through my parent contract, so that I can index everything in a subgraph.

Answer (score 1):

What you can actually do is to save a pointer to the parent contract into each generated contract. Thus, whenever you have an event you want to store into the parent contract, you can maybe interact with a function in it. But you may also want some type of verification to ensure that only child contracts can call the parent functions and not external contracts, so maybe you could make a mapping indexing the address of the generated child contracts, which will be able to call functions from the parent. What you can not do is to make the parent automatically look for events on the child's contracts.

Hope you find this information helpful :)

Comment: It was very helpful information as I'm quite new to Solidity development, thank you! I won't mark it as accepted answer yet, as I would like more insights :)

Comment: Can I ask you what information do you want to index?

Comment: I would like to index all the NFTs that those new "child" contracts will create or really any other data that I could find useful, it would be awesome if I could trigger events in the parent contract using functions inherited from the parent, and passing as arguments the data needed to trigger the parent event